# Add display: none to img, how to prevent the browser from sending image resource requests

Tags: html, css

Add display: none to img, the browser will still send image resource requests, how to prevent the browser from loading unnecessary image resources?

Add display: none to img, how to prevent the browser from loading unnecessary image resources?

Comment: Can you give a bit more context to your problem? For example, is the display: none within a media query (e.g. you don't want to show a particular image on a small device).

Answer (score 0):

Try `loading="lazy"`

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080" style="display: none;" loading="lazy" alt="">
```

Comment: Why would this work if the img would be within the viewport (i.e. 'above the fold')? It doesn't work, BTW, at least on my Edge/Chrome tests.

Answer (score -1):

To prevent the browser from loading unnecessary image resources, you can try the following:

1. Using Lazy Load: `<img src="path/to/image.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="Description of the image">`
2. JavaScript-Based Lazy Loading
3. Conditional Loading

Comment: Why would solution 1 work if the img would be within the viewport (i.e. 'above the fold')? It doesn't work, BTW, at least on my Edge/Chrome tests. And perhaps you could explain conditional loading - do you mean conditional on media queries for example? [We don't have enough info in the question yet to know if this is the case].

Comment: I implemented it by lazy loading of images:  `[<img data-src="path/to/real-image.jpg" src="data:image/png;base64,..."  style="display:none">`